# T-SQL XML Create multiply recurring fields under one parent

Tags: xml, t-sql

Trying to create XML with T-SQL. First time I've done this format and I'm not succeeding.

I need this:

```
<record>
    <MedicalRecordNumber>21QWYZ12345ABC</MedicalRecordNumber> 
    <DischargeDate>2018-06-01</DischargeDate>    
    <Procedures>
        <PrincipalProcedure>P01198</PrincipalProcedure> 
        <OtherProcedure>P03245</OtherProcedure> 
        <OtherProcedure>P05624</OtherProcedure> 
    </Procedures> 
</Record>
```

But closest I've come is this:

```
<record>
    <MedicalRecordNumber>JH26557923</MedicalRecordNumber>
    <DischargeDate>2018-03-12</DischargeDate>
    <Procedures code="Procedures">
        <PrincipalProcedure>abc1234</PrincipalProcedure>
    </Procedures>
    <OtherProcedures>
        <OtherProcedure>abc</OtherProcedure>
    </OtherProcedures>
    <OtherProcedures>
        <OtherProcedure>def</OtherProcedure>
    </OtherProcedures>
</record>
```

This is my query, where `Encounters` is the parent table and `Procedures` is the child table in a 1:many relationship:

```
select
    Encounters.MedicalRecordNumber,
    dbo.Encounters.DischargeDate,
    'Procedures' as 'Procedures/@code',
    Encounters.PrimaryProcedure as 'Procedures/PrincipalProcedure',
    (select 
         JHHSProcedures.ProcedureCode as OtherProcedure
     from  
         JHHSProcedures
     where 
         JHHSProcedures.MedicalRecordNumber = Encounters.MedicalRecordNumber
         and JHHSProcedures.DisDate = dbo.Encounters.DischargeDate
     for xml path('OtherProcedures'), type)
from  
    Encounters
for xml path('record');
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Community won't d your work for you. Please chek [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference this link for examples on using PATH Mode:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/examples-using-path-mode?view=sql-server-2017

A few adjustments and I think you'll get your desired output.

Having this line:

```
'Procedures' as 'Procedures/@code',
```

is what is causing:

```
<Procedures code="Procedures">
```

in your output.

Remove that, it isn't needed.

This line:

```
Encounters.PrimaryProcedure as 'Procedures/PrincipalProcedure',
```

will basically get you your sub node of Procedures with inner PrincipalProcedure.

Then a few tweaks to the nested select to bring in "OtherProcedures" with "Procedures":

```
    (SELECT field AS 'OtherProcedure' --The field as 'OtherProcedure'
    FROM ChildTable b
    WHERE ChildTable.Field = ParentTable.Field
            AND ChildTale.Date = ParentTable.Date
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS 'Procedures' --Don't set the node in the PATH here, entire nested select as 'Procedures' is what you want
```

Comment: I vote yours up as it provides all the information needed, but - at least for me - I felt the need to add a more elaborate *stand-alone* solution.

Comment: Thank you both for your thorough and helpful answers. I found both answers helpful and marked this one as accepted ONLY because it forced me to work through the solution step-by-step.

Answer (score 1):

Next time it would be great to add consumable test data, best was a *stand-alone* sceanrio [read about *MCVE*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I've done this for you by providing mockup tables.

Try it like this:

```sql
DECLARE @mockEncounters TABLE(MedicalRecordNumber VARCHAR(100),DischargeDate DATE,PrimaryProcedure VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockEncounters VALUES('21QWYZ12345ABC','20180601','P01198');

DECLARE @mockJHHSProcedures TABLE(MedicalRecordNumber VARCHAR(100),DisDate DATE,ProcedureCode VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockJHHSProcedures VALUES('21QWYZ12345ABC','20180601','P03245')
                                     ,('21QWYZ12345ABC','20180601','P05624');
```

--The query is rather close to your own one, but read my hints below:

```sql
SELECT 
    Encounters.MedicalRecordNumber,
    Encounters.DischargeDate,
    Encounters.PrimaryProcedure AS [Procedures/PrincipalProcedure],
    (SELECT 
         JHHSProcedures.ProcedureCode AS OtherProcedure
     FROM  
         @mockJHHSProcedures AS JHHSProcedures
     WHERE 
         JHHSProcedures.MedicalRecordNumber = Encounters.MedicalRecordNumber
         and JHHSProcedures.DisDate = Encounters.DischargeDate
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS [Procedures]
FROM  
    @mockEncounters AS Encounters
FOR XML PATH('record');
```

The result

```
<record>
  <MedicalRecordNumber>21QWYZ12345ABC</MedicalRecordNumber>
  <DischargeDate>2018-06-01</DischargeDate>
  <Procedures>
    <PrincipalProcedure>P01198</PrincipalProcedure>
    <OtherProcedure>P03245</OtherProcedure>
    <OtherProcedure>P05624</OtherProcedure>
  </Procedures>
</record>
```

With this line

```
    Encounters.PrimaryProcedure AS [Procedures/PrincipalProcedure],
```

... you are telling the engine: "Open the element `<Procedures>` and add the element `<PrincipalProcedure>`.

The sub-select calls each output `AS OtherProcedure` with an empty `PATH('')` this leads - run *alone* to this:

```
<OtherProcedure>P03245</OtherProcedure>
<OtherProcedure>P05624</OtherProcedure>
```

The `TYPE` will keep this as a native XML and this `AS [Procedure]`. The engine sees, that this element is opened already, no need to open another one. So the whole thing is placed into the current element.

Comment: This answer is extremely helpful and I'll be saving this to my XML notes. Thanks for taking the time to create a full working solution and thanks for suggesting how I can improve my posts.